# How can I set path in the fileupload control on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all how can I set path in the file upload control, I will get the path from database which I need to show it on the fileupload on page load or some other method. Can some one tell me how can I achieve  this

`<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />`

in my page load there is a code that will retrieve the path from db which I need show on fileupload control as its path

Comment: Which file upload control?

Comment: give us some example of the code you are using, or the markup

Answer (score 1):

This was slightly hard to find, but the answer here

[Assign file path to FileUpload Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661541/assign-file-path-to-fileupload-control)

indicates that it isn't possible due to security reasons, and provides an alternative method using a label.