# Paste file path into NeatUpload FileInput control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, neatupload

Using the [NeatUpload](https://neatupload.codeplex.com/) file-upload control

Is there a way I can paste a file path (instead of browsing) into an `InputFile` control? 
Say I have the path on the clipboard and javascript sets focus to the control, and the user manually pastes the clipboard contents using `ctrl+v`.

Right now, if I paste the clipboard, it doesn't seem to receive the file.  That is, the textual path does not seem to get accepted into the control.

Now, I've found these thread:
[Assign file path to FileUpload Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661541/assign-file-path-to-fileupload-control?rq=1)
and
[How can I set path in the fileupload control on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450569/how-can-i-set-path-in-the-fileupload-control-on-page-load?lq=1)
, but I thought maybe since NeatUpload has such influence over the control that there was another way - say, if the user pasted the file-path into a text box, then I could have the file-path available to code-behind.  Then, how would I get that path into the `InputFile` control?  I've read the NeatUpload docs and searched the forums, but I still need some advice or examples.

Is there a way to be able to *receive a paste event* into the InputFile control? Or, is there a way to get the path from a textbox into the upload sequence code?

Comment: What does your markup look like and what JavaScript are you using to paste from the clipboard?  *Can* JavaScript even *read* the clipboard?  That is, are you able to make this work for other elements in the page?

Comment: No, I'm not using script to do the pasting.  Say the user has the file path on the clipboard and pushes ctrl+v  now I want the script to accept the path into the file-upload control.  JS doesn't have to read the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reasons, there is no way to set any of the settings for this type of control.

However, a workaround is this:
Add a javascript (A simple `$('InputFileID').click();` will do nicely) function that will click the `Browse` button.  This will open the file-browsing dialogue.  Now the user can paste the clipboard right into the box in that dialogue.